# Put variable from Site.Master.Cs to Site.Master in C#

Tags: c#, .net, master-pages

I want to provibe a variable in my "`Page_Load`" event on the Site.Master.Cs and put this value in my Site.Master.

I've do this but it doesn't work :

```
<asp:Literal ID="myControl" runat="server">
    Hello
</asp:Literal>
```

And, in my Site.Master.Cs :

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{


    Literal litStreamHtml = (Literal)this.Master.FindControl("myControl");
    litStreamHtml.Text = "some text";

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are already on the masterpage, so you don't have to reference the master (only in case you use nested master pages.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Literal litStreamHtml = (Literal)this.FindControl("myControl");
    litStreamHtml.Text = "some text";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Agreed with Luuk, also you could just use

```
myControl.Text = "some text";
```